# Migrating from apply plugin to plugins{} block

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, plugins

I need to use the "apply false" annotation in a plugin block, but my plugins are applied the old way and now I am trying to migrate to the block structure.

old way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

what I am trying to switch to:

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44.2' apply false
}
```

However I have no idea what to do since commenting out the apply plugin lines and adding the block on top of my gradle file doesn't work exactly like I thought. I am getting the following error:

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\flutterapps\logitplus\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false]
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
```

these is are my two gradle files:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44.2' apply false
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }


android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    namespace "com.mladenovit.logitplus"
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }



    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.mladenovit.logitplus"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

and

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `apply false`?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265653154#comment3

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because you're adding ("placing on classpath") the `com.android.application` Gradle plugin twice – one in `build.gradle` in `buildscript.dependencies` as `classpath`, and then second time in `app/build.gradle` in the `plugins {}` block.

To fully migrate from imperative `apply` to declarative `plugins {}` block, make your `build.gradle` look like this:

```
rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

- Check out the [issue I created on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135392) to document the "imperative->declarative apply transition".
- I also recommend you check out the [example hello world app](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/hello_world) in the Flutte repo. It's fully migrated to declarative style.

#### PS

You don't need to use MultiDex because your `minSdkVersion` is already set to 21. [Learn more here](https://developer.android.com/build/multidex#mdex-on-l).

Comment: I just found out about pluginManagement  and dependencyResolutionManagement. Do I have to add these to settings.gradle?

Comment: Yes. For Flutter 3.10 it should look like this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/51251f2e57e3ed4758018aaa97b962722375bed7/examples/hello_world/android/settings.gradle

And for Flutter master: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/dbe0ccd8853dabdcb0f94ce2cdef892a1b10e48a/examples/hello_world/android/settings.gradle

Comment: Now i am getting a new error ` What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_5q52jc7u7qcth69jwukq68h18$_run_closure2@75e576bd] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: Are you applying com.android.application? You cannot do "apply false", otherwise Gradle won't be able to resolve it.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265653154#comment3 this what i am trying to achieve. Neverthless, when i remove the apply false from all plugins this is what I end up with:  Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'.
   > Cannot add a configuration with name 'androidJdkImage' as a configuration with that name already exists.

Comment: Why are you setting sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility to 17?
Android doesn't handle versions of Java bytecode above 8 well (or at all).

Comment: I did set them to 1.8 at first, but i didnt help at all, so i figured better set them to what i need anyway.

Comment: With the help of the links you provided I managed to set the gradle files correctly I think - big thanks for that mate. Nevertheless  I am still facing the problem: > 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

Comment: Happy to hear that! To fix that other error, you have to set compileOptions.sourceCompatibility and compileOptions.targetCompatibility to JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8, and then also set kotlinOptions.jvmTarget to 8 (or 1.8 - don't remember exactly).

Comment: Hi, if I helped you, please consider marking the answer as accpeted :)